# How to do multi-column layouts in shopify 2.0

Tags: css, shopify, shopify-template

I'm upgrading from a themekit theme to shopify 2.0 and I'm trying to figure out how to do multi-column layouts.  We have something like this.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            {% section 'blog-home-most-recent' %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            {% section 'blog-home-most-popular' %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I move the sections out to individual files, how do you wrap items like this?  Googled it and only find references to one specific multicolumn theme.

Comment: Is this a Shopify question or a Bootstrap question or a CSS question?

Comment: What I would do is combine those two sections into a single file and then add sidebar as a section block instead of it's own section.

Comment: @BrettDonald - this is a question about Shopify - they have made it so you can't nest sections in the v2.0 themes, which if I do what Sean S. recommends in migrating from the v1 theme leads to code duplication which I don't love - was trying to figure out how people create multi-column layouts in Shopify JSON templates - not a CSS question.